# Follow Up: Create an an array of objects from classname

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

I am following up on this question, [1268817](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268817/)

In the question, we find a way to create an isntance of an object given a the name (as a string) of the class.

But what about to create an array of those objects... how would one initialize that.

I was thinking something in the line of but doesnt seem to work

```
Object[] xyz = Class.forName(className).newInstance()[];
```

Comment: completely outside the question -> 
"Follow Up" -- would be a nice feature on SO -- linking a questions with the follow up questions and/or answers -- and also let the previous people who asked and answered to know that a follow up has been initiated...

Comment: @bushman, checkout meta.stackoverflow.com, where you can post and discuss such suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object objects = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Class.forName(classname), 10);
```

For an array of 10 elements.

Annoyingly it returns an object, instead of an object array.

As Tom points out, this is to allow:

```
Object objects = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(int.class, 10);
```

An int[] is not assignable to an Object[], so the return type has to be an Object. But it is still annoying as you very rarely want to do this.

Comment: That'll be because it can return an array of primitives.

Comment: Tom, could you please elaborate on that? what is the significance of returning an array of primitives

Comment: @Bushman, he means that if you had it create an array if ints, that could not be assigned to an Object[] array, so the method has to return Object, and not Object[].

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html):

```
Object[] xyz = Array.newInstance(Class.forName(className), 123);
```

and catch the appropriate exceptions.

Comment: You will need a cast in there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example creating an array of String:

```
// equiv to String strArray = new String()[10]

Class cls = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
String[] strArray = (String[]) Array.newInstance(cls, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(className);
Object xyz = Array.newInstance(c, length);
```