# Java how to instantiate a class from string

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create new class from a Variable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268817/create-new-class-from-a-variable-in-java)

I have a string

```
String className = "DummyClass"
```

Now I want to create a class object where the class name is **className** That is something like

```
Object className = new className() // I know it's not possible.
```

I want to know how to do this...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

["Using `java.lang.reflect`"](http://www.zahniser.net/%7Erussell/computer06/index.php?title=Using%20java.lang.reflect#chapter:constructor) will answer all your questions.  First fetch the `Class` object using `Class.forName()`, and then:

> If I want to instantiate a class that I retrieved with `forName()`, I have to first ask it for a `java.lang.reflect.Constructor` object representing the constructor I want, and then ask that `Constructor` to make a new object. The method `getConstructor(Class[] parameterTypes)` in `Class` will retrieve a `Constructor`; I can then use that `Constructor` by calling its method `newInstance(Object[] parameters)`:
>
> ```
> Class myClass = Class.forName("MyClass");
>
> Class[] types = {Double.TYPE, this.getClass()};
> Constructor constructor = myClass.getConstructor(types);
>
> Object[] parameters = {new Double(0), this};
> Object instanceOfMyClass = constructor.newInstance(parameters);
> ```

There is a `newInstance()` method on `Class` that might seem to do what you want.  **Do not use it**.  It silently converts checked exceptions to unchecked exceptions.

> Note that this method propagates any exception thrown by the nullary constructor, including a checked exception. Use of this method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would otherwise be performed by the compiler. The `Constructor.newInstance` method avoids this problem by wrapping any exception thrown by the constructor in a (checked) `InvocationTargetException`.

Comment: Since java 1.5, [constructor.newInstance()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)) is varargs, so `constructor.newInstance(new Double(0), this);` will do (instead of using the cumbersome `Object[]` way). Same goes for `Class.getConstructor()` (no need for ugly Class[])

Comment: What if the class is static? You wouldn't need a constructor right?

Comment: @advocate, a `static` class is just an inner class that does not have an implicit reference to an instance of its containing class.  It still needs to have a constructor.

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't worded properly Mike. I didn't need to call getConstructor() for my static class whatsoever, which is what my question was getting at. Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(command); // get the class named after their input
      Method listMethod = myClass.getDeclaredMethod("list"); // get the list method from the class
      Object returnType = listMethod.invoke(myClass, new Object[]{}); // run the list method

Comment: @advocate, if you're trying to invoke a static method, then you don't need the constructor, but you want to call invoke thus:  `Object returnValue = listMethod.invoke(null, argument0, argument1, argument2);`.  You pass in `null` as the value for `this` since static methods don't run in the context of an instance of the class.

Comment: What if there are no arguments? Just listMethod.invoke(null) ??

Comment: @advocate, Yes.  The `invoke` method is [variadic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), so you can  pass any number of arguments.

Comment: Thanks Mike. This is something I've only seen before in C code and so am thus unfamiliar with it. Had no idea it was implemented in Java.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `reflection`. For example,

```
Object o = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```

But `className` should contain full path to the class.

Comment: Do not use `Class.newInstance`.  The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) specifically says "Use of this method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would otherwise be performed by the compiler. The `Constructor.newInstance` method avoids this problem by wrapping any exception thrown by the constructor in a (checked) `InvocationTargetException`."

Comment: @limirus, Yeah.  It's buried pretty deep in the javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer to this question: [What is the difference between "Class.forName()" and "Class.forName().newInstance()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstance) which explains in detail how all this works.