# How can I instantiate a class with it's String Name?

Tags: java

I have an array of class names:

```
String[] myClasses = { "Hello", "World" };
```

Is there a way to instantiate a class with the string names ?
For example:

```
public SomeClassType getMyClass(String className) {
  ???
}

getMyClass("Hello"); // returns an instance of the Hello class
getMyClass("World"); // returns an instance of the World class
```

ps: obviously without looping through all the strings.

ps: Hello and World both extend SomeClassType

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268817/create-new-class-from-a-variable-in-java) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495785/java-how-to-instantiate-a-class-from-string)

Answer (score 2):

[Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/):

```
String className = "MyClass";
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(className);
MyClass ob = (MyClass) myClass.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Class#forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) to obtain a `Class type`, and later use `clazz.newInstance()` to get a Instance of the class.

The problem is that you need the full qualifier name (the name of the class and the package), if you dont have the full name, you can use `Reflection` to get iterate the packages and obtain the class you want.

You can see a working example [here](http://ideone.com/LlQtoM)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Java reflection tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/index.html). Here is an example:

```
public class Hello {

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Inside Hello foo()...");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> c;
        try {
            c = Class.forName("Hello");
            Hello h = (Hello) c.newInstance();
            h.foo();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```