# Instantiating a class with Reflection

Tags: java, class, object, reflection

```
class Start
{
  public static void main( String[] argv ) 
  {
      int argc =argv.length;
      if ( argc == 0 ) {
          System.err.println( "error");
          return;
      }

      try 
      { 
          Class<?> c = Class.forName( argv[argv.length-1] );
          //c kowalski = c.newInstance( );   
      }
      catch ( Exception e ) { System.out.println(e) ; return; }
    }
}
class Test implements InfoInterface
{
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("HI!");      
    }
    static int w;
    public int dodawanie (int a, int b)
    {
        w=a+b;
        return w;
    }
}
```

My problem is how can I create the object of `Test` class in `Start` class?
The `Test` class has to be added by command line.
In this program I have to get methods from `Test` class via object in `Start` class.

Comment: What's wrong with just calling `c.newInstance()` ?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want. If you want the names of the methods, you can get them from the `Class` object you refer to as `c`. Or do you want to actually *invoke* the methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create new class from a Variable in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268817/create-new-class-from-a-variable-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You can create dynamic object by just passing the name of the class with complete class path in the argument while executing the program from command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a new class instance by performing:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(argv[argv.length-1]);
Test t = (Test) c.newInstance( );
```

or, if you have more `InfoInterface` implementations:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(argv[argv.length-1]);
if (!InfoInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid interface specified");
}
Class<InfoInterface> iic = (Class<InfoInterface>) c;
InfoInterface ii = iic.newInstance();
```

---

Beware that you specify the full class name (including package name) in the argument used inside of your

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(argv[argv.length-1]);
```

line. You can of course also add the package string yourself:

```
String command = argv[argv.length-1];
Package p = InfoInterface.class.getPackage();
if (p != null) {
    command = p.getName() + "." + command;
}
Class<?> c = Class.forName(command);
```

assuming that the `Test` and other commands are in the same package as `InfoInterface`.

Comment: PS creating some kind of register containing all commands may be more prudent.