# Instantiate generic class from a String variable (Java)

Tags: java, string, class, generics

I am trying to instantiate a class given a String in Java. Something like this:

```
// Pseudocode
String name = "MyClass";
SomeClass<name> sc = new SomeClass<name>(parameter);
```

In my case, the constructor takes a `Class<E>` type. So I would pass `MyClass.class`. Ideally, take the string and append `.class`. It would turn out like this:

`SomeClass<name> sc = new SomeClass<name>(name.class);`

I was looking at the answer here: [Create new class from a Variable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268817/create-new-class-from-a-variable-in-java) but could not get it to work. Using the info from that link, I tried this:

```
String name = "MyClass";
Class className = Class.forName(name);
className param1;
Constructor con = className.getConstructor(className.class);
SomeClass<className> sc = con.newInstance(param1);
```

Of course, this doesn't work. How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: what is the signature of your target constructor?

Comment: Method signature is: `public SomeClass(Class<E> type) {}`

Comment: Well, seriously: you study the excellent tutorial from Oracle on how to do reflection. And then you keep trying. The thing is: reflection is awfully complicated. But when you just pick up some code somebody else wrote for you, you will not be able to grasp that. Meaning: all of this is documented; you will learn more by studying those sources; than from asking other people to explain it to you.

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need this?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am doing some automation testing with some XML files. There are a lot of classes for unmarshalling, so I wanted a way for a developer to just pass the name of the class they wanted to unmarshal the XML to. It saves a lot of coding and modifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are mostly a compile-time tool helping the compiler spot casting errors. Due to type erasure most of the generic information is lost at runtime - besides some basic information in reflection data (which doesn't really help you here).

Let's assume your constructor looks like this:

```
public SomeClass( Class<T> param ) { ... }
```

Due to type erasure at runtime it looks like this (when being called):

```
public SomeClass( Class param ) { ... }
```

As you can see there's no generic information so to get it you'd use `SomeClass.getConstructor( Class.class )`.

Then you can invoke it using `newInstance( Class.forName("java.lang.String") )`. 
Again you see that you're basically able to pass in *any* class as a parameter which is due to generics being a compile-time tool, i.e. the *compiler* applies those checks while the runtime trusts the compiled code.

If you need to employ any boundaries you'd need to either use a different approach or check for the correct class being passed inside the constructor (e.g. by using the method `Class#isAssignableFrom()`).

When assigning the created instance to a variable you need to use a wildcard, i.e. `SomeClass<?> sc`, or a raw type, i.e. `SomeClass sc` (I'd suggest using the wildcard). Of course the compiler then can't allow you to call any method that is only present in some classes (e.g. in `MyClass`) since it simply doesn't know (and it can't know the class definition from just a name).

**Edit:**

In the hope of being able to clarify the last part I'll try and add another example.

Assume `MyClass` had a method `foo()` and `SomeClass` has a method `T getTypeInstance()`. If your variable type would be `SomeClass<MyClass> sc` you could do a call `sc.getTypeInstance().foo()` since the compiler knows that `T` is bound to `MyClass`.

However, when using reflection that information is lost, i.e. since you'd have to use `SomeClass<?> sc` the compiler would not know the return type of `getTypeInstance()` and thus wouldn't allow calls to `foo()`.

If you know that all classes you could pass as a parameter implement the same interface you could do something like `SomeClass<CommonInterface> sc` which would compile since `Constructor#newInstance()` returns a raw type and thus compiler checks are disabled here. In that case you could add `foo()` to `CommonInterface` and be able to call it - at least unless you break the code.

The problem with the above is that you could also pass `String.class` to the constructor, which the compiler and runtime would allow but which is still wrong since `String` doesn't implement `CommonInterface`. Hence you'd get exceptions when trying to create the instance, cast it to `CommonInterface` or call `foo()` on it - unless you add a check in your constructor that rejects any parameter that isn't a class being assignable to `CommonInterface` (e.g. by checking `CommonInterface.class.isAssignableFrom( param )`).

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. So from what you are saying is that the compiler won't know the methods if I continue to use reflection? Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: @Flow I'm not sure I understand your question correctly so I'll add an update on how I interpret your question. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `Class#isAssignableFrom()` or `Constructor#newInstance()`. I have never seen that notation before. In any case, I do know all the classes that can be passed through. However, there are way too many methods that I would need to put in the interface. I'm using this for unmarshalling XML files so there will be a lot of classes and methods. Thank you though, I just need to think of a new way to achieve my goal.

Comment: @Flow `Class#isAssignableFrom(...)` is JavaDoc notation (or at least similar) meaning method `isAssignableFrom(...)` in class `Class`. I normally use it to not confuse it with static methods, e.g. `String.valueOf(...)` would mean the static method in class `String` while `String#length()` would be the method `length()` without telling whether it is static or not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your generic class looks something like this:

```
public GenericClass(Class<T> param) {
    System.out.println(param.getName());
}
```

Your code could look like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String type = "java.lang.String";
    Class g = GenericClass.class;
    Constructor c = g.getConstructor(Class.class);
    GenericClass<?> genericClass = (GenericClass<?>) c.newInstance(Class.forName(type));
}
```

And you'll see in the console that it prints "java.lang.String".

This works because in reflection, everything must have a type, and since generics have no type in compilation, it shows up as `java.lang.Class`, not `java.lang.Class<T>`. So, to get the constructor, you must tell it it find the constructor taking a class object. Then, simply use `Class.forName` to find the class in `type`, and call the constructor, passing in that class.

Comment: I get `ClassNotFoundException` when I do this. I'm assuming it's because of the above explanation by Thomas. Trying to call a method from `GenericClass` can't be done because it doesn't know the class during compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I see some errors in your code:

What is: `className param1;` ? You can't use `className` that is an object of class `Class` as a type.

The invokation:

```
Constructor con = className.getConstructor(className.class);
```

returns a constructor of the class "className" with a parameter of type "className". Is that your request? (For example if your class is `ArrayList` is the constructor taking 1 argument of type `ArrayList`)

The code:

```
SomeClass<className> sc = con.newInstance(param1);
```

Is syntactically not correct. The method `newInstance` returns an `Object` of type `T`. Try to assign it to a variable of type `Object`.

---

Here is how your code should seems:

```
String name = "MyClass";
Class className = Class.forName(name);
String param1 = "something";
// Using a constructor that use a String as parameter
Constructor con = className.getConstructor(String.class); 
Object sc = con.newInstance(param1);
```

Comment: I was following the code in the linked post. I thought `Param1Type` was the class you wanted the parameter to be since, in my code, `Param1Type` could not be resolved. I want to do this basically: `SomeClass<AnotherClass> sc = new SomeClass<AnotherClass>(AnotherClass.class)`. `AnotherClass` would be the given String.

Comment: Yes.... you are right. Thank you Sotirios.