# How to create dynamic method in android with the received method string from server

Tags: android, dynamic-class-loaders, dynamic-class-creation, dexmaker

I want to create a dynamic class or method. The server sends the complete class as the response. I want to use the response to create a dynamic class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new class from a Variable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268817/create-new-class-from-a-variable-in-java)

Comment: No. I'm sending class in response. So I just want to load those into the class loader and use it (like generic class loader).

Comment: You want to create classes from raw string source? It's possible. But **highly not recommended**. Google for `cglib` or `javassist`. But I cant imagine the real business case that require compiling classes dynamically.

Comment: We want to send class that contains API keys, encryption key generation methods for the security.

Comment: Yes, we want to create the class from the raw string.

Comment: Just imagine: you send a complete guide of how to generate keys from server to the application. Anyone can grab it, it's absolutely not secure. I recommend you to take a look at asymmetrical cryptography.

Comment: I'm doing this to avoid code extraction during APK decompilation.

Comment: APK decompilation will give attacker everything required to request your method from server and use for generate new keys. Doing this is not secure.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But Is there any way to do so? I'm just asking to learn.

Comment: Answer depends of what you're trying to protect. May be apk resources, network requests, server content. A lot of varieties.