# Can variables be used to create object in Java?

Tags: java, class, oop

How do I do something like this? I want to take command line arguments like `Circle 10` or `Rectangle 20 30` and create objects of the corresponding classes.

```
class Circle{
    //Some lines here
}

class Rectangle{
    //Some lines here
}

public class Perimeter{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0; i< args.length; i++){
            String shape = args[0];
            shape curr_shape = new shape();
            System.out.println(curr_shape.getPerimeter( <arguments> ));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new object from a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268817/create-new-object-from-a-string-in-java)

Comment: I have created all the classes I need. I need to create objects of those classes using variables. I think the link describes how to create classes with string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Class.forName()` and reflection to create an instance, like @Milgo proposed, but I would recommend to create a simple `switch/case`. Your task looks like some training, so probably that would be best option for you.

```java
Object form;
switch (type) {
  case "Circle":
    form = new Circle();
    break;
  case "Rectangle":
    form = new Rectangle();
    break;
}
```

Comment: Additionally you could have an abstract base class `Form` with an abstract `getPerimeter()` method, which Circle, Rectangle etc. implement. Then change `Object form` to `Form form` and have a `return form.getPerimeter()` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Although you could use reflection (ie the dark arts), you can do it with minimal code if all shapes have the same constructor signature of say `List<Double>` (which includes integers like your example):

```
private static Map<String, Function<List<Double>, Shape>> factories = 
    Map.of("Circle", Circle::new, "Rectangle", Rectangle::new); // etc

public static Shape createShape(String input) {
    String[] parts = input.split(" ");
    String name = parts[0];
    List<Double> dimensions = Arrays.stream(parts)
      .skip(1) // skip the name
      .map(Double::parseDouble) // convert String terms to doubles
      .collect(toList());
    return factories.get(name).apply(dimensions); // call constructor
}

interface Shape {
    double getPerimeter();
}

static class Rectangle implements Shape {
    private double height;
    private double width;

    public Rectangle(List<Double> dimensions) {
        height = dimensions.get(0);
        width = dimensions.get(1);
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * (height + width);
    }
}

static class Circle implements Shape {
    double radius;

    public Circle(List<Double> dimensions) {
        radius = dimensions.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return (double) Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }
}
```

Comment: `float`? Why not `double`?

Comment: @MCEmperor fine, changed to double. Doesn't affect the concept.